# How can I skip before_validations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have code that updates/fixes some model data in my `before_validation` callbacks.

However, I'd like to be able to still run validations to see if a model is ok as-is.

More specifically, i'd like to know if a record in the database is valid or not. So I'd like to be able to load a value and ask `.valid?` without having my callbacks run that would affect the answer.

So, I tried this (and a few variations) but it didn't work:

`skip_callback :validation, :before, unless: ->{self.changed?}`

The docs for `skip_callback` are poor, so I'm not sure I'm using it properly. Can this be made to work?

Thanks.

Comment: The example here http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_callback says `:validate` not `:validation`, could that be the issue?

Comment: @Iceman it's `:validation`.  You can find all the `validation` callbacks using this `Model._validation_callbacks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [APIDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_callback) skip_callback takes `callback_name`, then `*filter_lists` as arguments (then a block).

`filter_list` must include your callback method name. Like this below.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  before_validation :set_name

  skip_callback :validation, :before, :set_name, unless: -> { self.changed? }

  def set_name
    self.name ||= 'foobar'
  end
end

#<User:0x007ffcd7165248 id: 2, name: nil, created_at: Fri, 03 Feb 2017 01:10:37 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Fri, 03 Feb 2017 01:10:37 UTC +00:00>

User.find(2).valid? # returns false

user = User.find(2)
user.updated_at = Time.now
user.valid? # returns true, because it invokes :set_name before validation
```

Comment: Right, seems like there is no way to avoid all before_validations, or reference nameless ones implemented via lambdas. Thanks.

Comment: @z5h you can simply list all of them

Answer (score 1):

You can skip any callback. You have to skip the callback and do the transaction and set the call back again.
`Model.skip_callback(:callback_name, :callback_position, :callback_action_name)`

For eg.

```
class ModelName < ApplicationRecord 
    before_validation :validation_action
    
    def validation_action
    end 

end
```

To skip this validation when calling ModelName

```
ModelName.skip_validation(:validation, :before, :validation_action)
ModelName.create!()
ModelName.set_validation(:validation, :before, :validation_action)
```

Similarly, you can skip all callbacks from [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

> .. I'd like to be able to .. ask .valid? without having my callbacks run that would affect the answer.

Make the validation conditional on an `attr_accessor`.

```ruby
# banana.rb
attr_accessor :use_validation_callbacks
before_validation :derp, if: { |b| b.use_validation_callbacks }
def initialize(*)
  self.use_validation_callbacks = true
  super
end

# elsewhere
banana = Banana.new
banana.use_validation_callbacks = false
banana.valid?
```